# Prepared statement does not match bind variables even though it does?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

As far as I can tell, I select 6 columns from the table, and I bind 6 variables so why does it tell me that it does not match?

This is for a rating script where people can vote cars.

This script works with the Insert/Select/Union but I noticed that everything was getting really slow when people voted the images from the folder structure so I would like to move the selected images to another folder where they can be accessed faster, however I seem to get a problem when trying to bind the result. This is usually not a problem for me.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening in this particular case ?

#### Update:

I forgot to include the category variables SORRY they are in the real script just defined up the script... So why all the downvotes? I told you the SQL works- I just tried to improve it.

```
$cat1 = 1;
$cat2 = 2:
$cat3 = 3;
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" INSERT INTO cars_daily ( cars_daily_identifier, cars_daily_source, cars_daily_views, cars_daily_votes, cars_daily_rating, cars_daily_category) "
        . " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
        . " FROM cars_bcar "
        . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) "
        . " UNION "
        . " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
        . " FROM cars_car "
        . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) "
        . " UNION "
        . " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
        . " FROM cars_car "
        . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) ");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $cat1, $cat2, $cat3);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Success SELECT/INSERT";
    echo "<br><br>";
} else {
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r($stmt->error);
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Fail SELECT/INSERT";
}

        $stmt->bind_result($cars_car_id, $cars_cars_source, $cars_car_views, $cars_car_votes, $cars_car_rating, $cars_car_category);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            copy("models/$cars_cars_source", "daily/$cars_cars_source");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried running such a statement in mysql (e.g. using phpMyAdmin or a similar tool)? if so, what was returned?

Comment: You need a placeholder for each value. `$cat1, $cat2, $cat3` are single values?

Comment: Also what are you expecting to fetch/bind(_result)?

Comment: Why all the down votes?? yes this sql works... its just the fetch that does not, i dont deserve all these downvotes

Comment: i have all the $cat variables, i just forgot to include them in this example sorry for that they are defined up in the script.. but thanks for so many downvotes i told you the sql works, i just tried to improve it and fetch the results from the select querys...

Comment: I've stopped asking question about 'improvement'. Anything that is not 'how it should be' or "beyond the scope of debugging" get down voted. An syntax error or already answered question will get marked as duplicate but not down voted. May i suggest https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

An [*INSERT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) query won't yield records (like a [*SELECT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) would) even if the values to be inserted come from a *SELECT* statement.

#### A solution

One option is to run the *INSERT* query and then run a separate *SELECT* to fetch the values that were inserted.

```
$selectSQL = " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
    . " FROM cars_bcar "
    . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) "
    . " UNION "
    . " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
    . " FROM cars_car "
    . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) "
    . " UNION "
    . " (SELECT cars_car_id, cars_car_source, cars_car_views, cars_car_votes, cars_car_rating, cars_car_category "
    . " FROM cars_car "
    . " WHERE cars_car_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) ";
//run the INSERT statement
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" INSERT INTO cars_daily ( cars_daily_identifier, cars_daily_source, cars_daily_views, cars_daily_votes, cars_daily_rating, cars_daily_category) " . $selectSQL);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $cat1, $cat2, $cat3);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Success SELECT/INSERT";
    echo "<br><br>";
} else {
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r($stmt->error);
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Fail SELECT/INSERT";
}
$stmt->close(); //close the prepared statement
//run the SELECT statement
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($selectSQL);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $cat1, $cat2, $cat3);
$stmt->execute()
$stmt->bind_result($cars_car_id, $cars_cars_source, $cars_car_views, $cars_car_votes, $cars_car_rating, $cars_car_category);
    
    .
```

Comment: If `$cat1`, `$cat2`, or `$cat3` have more than 1 value this wont work as expected, if they are 1 value `=` would be better than `in`.

Comment: Hmm... why do you say that won't work as expected? The OP appears to be binding each as an integer (given the first parameter of `bind_param()`...

Comment: It was my solution too if i could not make it work in one query, thanks anyway... got alot of downvotes tho... which idont deserve.

Comment: I am not really sure why all the downvotes but if I had to guess, perhaps others wanted to see exactly what the output was (e.g. any error messages, blank variables, etc)...

Comment: If `$cat1` is `1,2` then the `1` and `2` need to be bound independently. The placeholders are quoted/escaped per value. The `,` would break the `i` declaration.